# My TCP client does not connect to my TCP server

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcpserver

These are my first steps with client-server communication via TCP in C#. Server is stuck after "Waiting for Client..." message. Client shows "Error: Not Connected to server". What's wrong?

Server code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MyTCPServer
{
    public class MyTCPServerClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener listener = null;
            int servPort = 55437;

            try 
            {
                listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, servPort);
                listener.Start();
            } 
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se.ErrorCode + ": " + se.Message);
                Environment.Exit(se.ErrorCode);
            }

            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netStream = null;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Client...");
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Get Stream...");
                netStream = client.GetStream();
                Console.Write("Handling client - ");

                int bytesRcvd;
                int totalBytesEchoed = 0;
                byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[10000];

                while ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length)) > 0) 
                {
                    netStream.Write(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);
                    totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("echoed {0} bytes.", totalBytesEchoed);

                netStream.Close();
                client.Close();

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                netStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MyTCPClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Demonstration eines synchron agierenden TcpClienten.
    /// </summary>
    public class MyTCPClientClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] byteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");

            //IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.16");
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;

            int servPort = 55437;

            TcpClient client = null;
            NetworkStream netStream = null;

            try {
                client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, servPort));

                if (!client.Connected) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Not Connected to server");
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Connected to server... sending echo string");

                netStream = client.GetStream();

                netStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server...", byteBuffer.Length);

                int totalBytesRcvd = 0;
                int bytesRcvd = 0;

                while (totalBytesRcvd < byteBuffer.Length) {
                    if ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(byteBuffer, totalBytesRcvd,
                            byteBuffer.Length - totalBytesRcvd)) == 0) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection closed prematurely.");
                        break;
                    }
                    totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Received {0} bytes from server: {1}", totalBytesRcvd,
                                  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, totalBytesRcvd));

            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            } 
            finally {
                if (netStream != null) netStream.Close();
                if (client != null) client.Close();
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw: this is not how any "real" TCP server would be written, mostly because it either scales to 1 client, or uses thread-per-client (equally non-scalable); code for "good" TCP servers is either horribly horribly complex (buffer pools, shared workers, etc), or uses alternative APIs that hide all that for you; happy to advise on that if it is of interest - and it might not be needed if this is just an example. My real point here is: don't take the example seriously: *nobody would ever write a TCP server that way*

Comment: For sure. It is an example. I'd be happy to take your advice on said topics.

Comment: well, if I were writing a TCP server today, I'd start with "Kestrel" as the underlying server, which uses the "pipelines" API; a length discussion (with examples, and links to github etc) starts here: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, servPort));
```

Comment: That did it. But why, I thought connection would be established automatically because address and port are already passed in constructor...

Comment: @oliver that's very different; read the end of "remarks" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient__ctor_System_Net_IPEndPoint_

Comment: Hmm, that is weird because Connect does not have an overload with no arguments. So it requires address+port, but I have already passed that to the constructor (which requires calling Connect...). So there is no real sense in having a constructor that accepts address+port, right? Or am I missing something?